# Amazon S3 file 'Access Denied' exception in Cross-Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've 2 AWS accounts. Account A has S3 bucket 'BUCKET' in which I've put file using Java api. I've configured my 'BUCKET' policy to allow cross-account file publishing.
But, when I try to open this file from Account A, it says `AccessDenied`Access Denied with hostId and requestId.

This file is published through Account B using java api, and this file has same size as that published through api. I tried to change file sizes and the new sizes were shown on AWS S3 console.
Here is my bucket policy:

```
    {
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1357935677554",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1357935647218",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTB:user/accountb-user"
        },
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1357935676138",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTB:user/accountb-user"
        },
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1357935676138",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTB:user/accountb-user"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1357935647218",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTA:user/accounta-user"
        },
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1357935676138",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTA:user/accounta-user"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1357935676138",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTA:root"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
    }
]
```

}

The problem is when I try to download/open this file from Account A, I'm not able to open it.

Comment: Have you managed to resolve the Issue? I'm also having this problem.

Comment: Yes, you need to use 's3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucket, key, inputFile).withAccessControlList(acl))'

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that by default, when AWS (cli or SDK) upload a file it grants access to the uploader only through `s3` ACLs.

In that case, to allow the owner to read the uploaded file, the uploader has to explicitly grant access to the owner of the bucket during the upload. Ex:

- with the `aws` CLI (documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-object.html)): `aws s3api put-object --bucket <bucketname> --key <filename> --acl bucket-owner-full-control`
- with the `nodejs` API (documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property)): you have to set the `params.ACL` property of the `AWS.S3.upload` method to `"bucket-owner-full-control"`

In parallel, you can also ensure that the Bucket Owner Has Full Control with the bucket policy, (additional documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html)):

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Grant Owner Full control dev",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTB:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: Still something strange, if you don't do it, the bucket owner has the right to remove those files.