# S3 cross account access: Reading an object in own bucket, written by another account

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

**Background:**

I have two accounts `A` and `B`. Account `A` owns a bucket `my-bucket`. I have given account `B` access to this bucket -- account `B` can read objects from and write objects to this bucket. This is working as expected.

However, account `A` can only read those objects in `my-bucket` that it has written on its own. Although it can list even those objects that account `B` has written, it cannot read those.

Below is what I see when I try to download all objects from `my-bucket` using AWS CLI with AWS configuration of account `A`.

```
download: s3://my-bucket/PN1492646400000.csv to tp/PN1492646400000.csv
download: s3://my-bucket/PN1491264000000.csv to tp/PN1491264000000.csv
download: s3://my-bucket/PN1493942400000.csv to tp/PN1493942400000.csv
download failed: s3://my-bucket/PN1503346865232.csv to tp/PN1503346865232.csv An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied
download: s3://my-bucket/PN1495389670000.csv to tp/PN1495389670000.csv
download: s3://my-bucket/PN1496685403000.csv to tp/PN1496685403000.csv
download: s3://my-bucket/PN1497945130000.csv to tp/PN1497945130000.csv
download: s3://my-bucket/PN1500508800000.csv to tp/PN1500508800000.csv
```

As one can see, I could download all files, but `PN1503346865232.csv` (this was written by account `B` using a java method `putObject`).

**What I tried so far:**

I have looked into the following two questions:

1. [Amazon S3 file 'Access Denied' exception in Cross-Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33236192/amazon-s3-file-access-denied-exception-in-cross-account?rq=1): One of the comment asks to do a putObject with `acl`, but does not specify what `acl`.
2. [S3: User cannot access object in his own s3 bucket if created by another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34055084/s3-user-cannot-access-object-in-his-own-s3-bucket-if-created-by-another-user?rq=1): This talks about stopping account B from putting objects into `my-bucket` without giving ownership access. *Does just putting this constraint help me get full access?*

This is how I tried to put the ACL while putting the object in the java code.

```
AccessControlList acl = new AccessControlList();
acl.grantPermission(new CanonicalGrantee(S3_BUCKET_OWNER_ID), Permission.FullControl);
PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(S3_BUCKET, remoteCleanedPrismFilename, fileStream, null)
                        .withAccessControlList(acl);
s3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest);
```

It throws exception saying: `com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Invalid id`

**Questions:**

1. *I wonder how am I supposed to get this ID. Is it not the aws account ID i.e. a 10-12 digit number?*
2. *Even if I find this ID, will giving this ACL same as `bucket-owner-full-
   control`?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This post got so many views, but not a single answer!

To help others, I am posting some workarounds that I found from my research so far. After these workarounds, account `A` is able to access the objects created by account `B`.

In the `java` code that is running in account `B`, I explicitly set the ACL on the object that is to be created.

```
AccessControlList acl = new AccessControlList();
acl.grantPermission(new CanonicalGrantee(S3_BUCKET_OWNER_ID), Permission.FullControl);
PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(S3_BUCKET, remoteCleanedPrismFilename, fileStream, null)
                        .withAccessControlList(acl);
s3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest);
```

Here `S3_BUCKET_OWNER_ID` is the canonical ID of account `A`. Please note that it is not the AWS account ID that we know and I do not know a better way, to find this out, than the following

```
aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket my-bucket --key PN1491264000000.csv --output text --profile accountA
```

This is still not an elegant solution according to me and I believe something better exists. I will edit this answer once I find something better.

**Edit:**

Canonical ID of the bucket owner can be found more elegantly as follows:

```
String s3BucketOwnerId = s3Client.getBucketAcl(S3_BUCKET).getOwner().getId();
```